# Hacer una clase para todos los alert

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero hacer una clase en base a los **alert** que aparecen en mi aplicación, pero lo que quiero es saber como hacer una clase para que funcione con los diferentes id's de cada uno de los alert que aparecen en la apliación, es decir, sin importar el id que tenga, la clase sea capaz de detectarlos y que funcione igual para todos.

```
<style>
a:hover path { 
    fill: #d9534f;
}
```

```
            <center>
            <div style="margin: -25px;">
                <svg width="120" height="130" margin-top="-3%">
                  <a href="#" onclick="alertaForm()" id="alertaForm">
                    <path d="M   0   0  L 150   0 L 120 120 L 60  80 L   0 120 Z" fill="#db2525"/>

                    <text x="60" y="50"fill="#FFFFFF" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">
                      Formulario 1 de 7
                    </text>
                  </a>
                </svg>
            </div>
            </center>

                <div class="" id="formulario0">

                </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function alertaForm() {
                document.getElementById("formulario0").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="alertaPrueba">  <button type="button" id="LinkClose" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><h2> Formulario <b> 1 de 7 </b><h/h2></div>';
                }
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#alertaForm').click(function(){
                       $('#alertaPrueba').show('fade'); 

                       setTimeout(function (){
                           $('#alertaPrueba').hide('fade');
                       }, 1000);
                    });

                    $('#LinkClose').click(function (){
                        $('#aleraPrueba').hide('fade');
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Quiero poder hacer eso con todos lo alert de mi aplicación, pero sin importar el id que tenga lo detecte.

Comment: Simplemente define una clase en tu CSS y aplícala al elemento que quieras con el atributo class.

Comment: Me refiero a como hacer una clase para los alert, no para los estilos, es decir, como tengo muchos fomularios, evitar repetir esa función 20 veces si tengo 20 formularios...

Comment: Metes la función en un script (comun.js) y lo importas en los formularios donde la necesites.